# Trigger JToolBarHelper::save

Tags: joomla3.0, virtuemart, eventtrigger

I will explain what I'm trying to do:

I'm customizing joomla 3.0 with virtuemart 3.4

I need to automatically change the order status when an order is imported in local software or when the items are shipped.
This is possible with CSVI and works great.

Now I would like to to follow:

everyday, at the certan time, fire a cronjob that send to customer the email of order status, exept the shipped.

I would like to achieve this solution loading the orders.php where I've just said that all orders "shipped" are no flagged, the other are flagged.

NOW THE POINT:

I need to trigger onpage load the "Update order status" button that is a

```
JToolBarHelper::save('updatestatus', vmText::_('COM_VIRTUEMART_UPDATE_STATUS'));
```

Anyone has an Idea?

Answer (score 1):

regarding

> need to trigger "Update order status" button

syntax of save is

```
JToolBarHelper::save( $task = 'save', $alt = 'Save' )
```

where task is name of function defined in your controller. in your case its 'updatestatus'

now point is how to call controller function?

1)you can call function of class by instantiating.
2) you can redirect user to path 'index.php?option=com_componentname&task=controllername.functionName'